# bitshares api implementation using php

Tags: cryptocurrency

I am interested in seeing some PHP class with some working examples making trades on the Bitshares DEX. I found https://github.com/carlo-fontanos/bitshares-api-php but it requires a running full node.

I don't want to have to run Bitshares, but want to connect to a node that is running somewhere else. If this code does not exist anywhere, I would be interested in building it. any help please

Answer (score 0):

You can update RPC endpoint URL to match your requirement.
You can see that in **index.php** line 9.